# Solution to the visual studio's "Login failed for user ..." when opening db in server explorer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

If you follow this tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application, you might get the error message that says "Login failed for user xxx"  when trying to check your DB in the View -> Server Explorer.

There seems to be many solutions to fix this, but none here have helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I pulled this answer from various websites and articles:

It seems that if you have previously installed visual studio 2010, which installs SQL Express, the SQL express will take precedence over LocalDB. So in fact my DB was installed in the SQL Express DB, not in the LocalDB, although my connection string says:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="EMTContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=EMT2;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

As it says here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx#enabling:

"If SQL Express is installed (included in Visual Studio 2010) then the database is created on your local SQL Express instance (.\SQLEXPRESS). If SQL Express is not installed then Code First will try and use LocalDb ((localdb)\v11.0) - LocalDb is included with Visual Studio 2012.

Note: SQL Express will always get precedence if it is installed, even if you are using Visual Studio 2012"

So the solutions was to install sql server management studio, find the SQL Express, and then my db created by Code first migration.

One last things I am thinkin, is that should I replace the connection string "LocalDB.." with "Sql express"  snippet? At least it is working, even left as it is?